# check if firebase record exist and return bool

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to check firebase record and perform subsequent logics,

```
Future<bool> isAlreadyThere(selectedPropertyId) async {
 final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

 var myMapQuery = Firestore.instance
    .collection("props")
    .where('xxx', isEqualTo: xxxid)
    .where('yyy', isEqualTo: user.uid);
 var querySnapshot=  await myMapQuery.getDocuments();
 var totalEquals= querySnapshot.documents.length;
 return totalEquals > 0;
}
```

and in the `onTap()` of widget ,

```
bool isThere=isAlreadyThere(suggestion.documentID) as bool;
 if (isThere) {//do stuff here}
```

errors,
*type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast*

I know its the casting , but tried removing and some other ways as well , wont work.

Comment: You have to await the Future, right, just like you are with getDocuments()?  It doesn't instantly produce a value.

Comment: You forgot to handle the `Future`. Use `await` or `.then()`.

Comment: cant use async modifier on widget , let me try .then()

Comment: There is no widget in the code you shared. But if the call to `isAlreadyThere` is in your `build` method, you'll need to either use a `FutureBuilder` or use `setState()` to get the state from the database to the render method.

Answer (score 1):

`await` is missing in where the query

```
Future<bool> isAlreadyThere(selectedPropertyId) async {
 final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

 var myMapQuery = (await Firestore.instance
    .collection("props")
    .where('xxx', isEqualTo: xxxid)
    .where('yyy', isEqualTo: user.uid));
   var querySnapshot=  await myMapQuery.getDocuments();
   var totalEquals= querySnapshot.documents.length;
   return totalEquals > 0;
}
```

Use method like

```
isAlreadyThere(suggestion.documentID).then((value) {
     if (value) {//do stuff here}
    });
```